# Firefox: prevent new items added to about:newtab

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When a new tab is opened in Firefox, by default it displays the "new tab" tab content. This new tab content displays click-able thumbnails.

I'd like to customize this set of tabs thumbnails *and* prevent Firefox from changing the tabs once they have been set (preferably without pinning). That is, prevent Firefox from adding new tabs even if there are more slots available. To be clear, I don't want to disable the new tab page, which is easily accomplished from `about:config`.

How is this possible without using an [add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/super-start/?src=amo-similar-addons)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Pin the website to the new tab page.
2. In the location bar, type: `about:config`
3. Search for: `browser.newtab`
4. Set **browser.newtabpage.columns** to: 1
5. Set **browser.newtabpage.rows** to: 1
6. Ensure only one entry exists for the **browser.newtabpage.pinned** value.